# ovirt engine fails with access error: SsoSession does not have property 'engineUrl'

Tags: ovirt

FQDN is right, DNS lookup works fine. when I try to access UI server throws error **'org.ovirt.engine.core.sso.utils.SsoSession' does not have the property 'engineUrl'.** here is the stack trace

```
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'org.ovirt.engine.core.sso.utils.SsoSession' does not have the property 'engineUrl'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:568) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.12.Final.jar:1.0.12.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:229) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.12.Final.jar:1.0.12.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110) [jastow-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139) [javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1.jar:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203) [javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1.jar:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-impl-3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1.jar:3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:917) [jastow-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.login_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fredirect_005f1(login_jsp.java:541)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.login_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f1(login_jsp.java:515)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:191)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jastow-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791) [jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433) [jastow-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.5.Final]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file /etc/ovirt-engine/engine.conf.d/11-setup-sso.conf and add the entry - 1. ENGINE_URL="XXXXXXX"
2. SSO_CALLBACK_PREFIX_CHECK=false
3. restart ovirt-engine

Hope this helps